# how to fix “django-admin not recognizable error in pycharm”

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-admin

I am trying to create the python project in the same environment as previous project but i'm having an error message that it does not recognizes the "django-admin" command please help me to solve this issue.whenever i try to run my  admin project i usually get the message (is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file).[please click on this link to view my screenshot of the above error message i usually encounter when i try to run the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSnId.jpg)

Comment: Is django installed in your virtual environment?

Comment: it worked thank you..how i do i star your answer?

Comment: There is two way to create virutal environment  using ```virtualenv --system-site-packages your_env_name``` and  ```virtualenv your_env_name```. Using first command will install all package in your venv , but not when using second.
So if you are using second command then yes you have to install again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to install Django in your enviroment

```
pip install Django
```

in your command line